# How to rotate the object around z axis using Lean touch asset in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am developing an Android Augment reality application using ARCore in Unity3d. I found an asset called Lean touch for scale,rotate, and drag the objects in unity asset store. All the functionalities worked fine, but i want to rotate the game object only on z axis. How can i rotate the object around z axis using Lean touch asset?

Comment: did you try watching the tutorials about lean touch asset if not this might help you [lean touch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-HZiZoWAtM)

Comment: @Ginxxx that video seems to only talk about rotation and scaling, and all the other videos I've seen don't discuss rotation around other/multiple axes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotation along a specific axis is available in lean touch plus. However you will have to pay for the plus version in the asset store. hope it helps.